# Why does renaming reg.exe on Windows Server 2008 x64 causes it to fail to run?

Tags: windows-server-2008, reverse-engineering, rename, crt

I've got a neat question here.

There's a utility called reg.exe thats been shipped with Windows for quite some time. Its very handy to import .reg files from scripts, modify values from scripts, etc, etc. So when making a copy of it for a script scenario ("Why not use the copy in system32?" -> Software Restriction Policies, personal pref, etc) I noticed that renaming it makes it fail silently:

Windows Server 2008 x64:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.0.6001]
Copyright (c) 2006 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Windows\system32>reg.exe
ERROR: Invalid syntax.
Type "REG /?" for usage.

C:\Windows\system32>copy reg.exe reg2.exe
        1 file(s) copied.

C:\Windows\system32>reg2.exe

C:\Windows\system32>reg2.exe /?


C:\Windows\system32>reg.exe /?

REG Operation [Parameter List]

  Operation  [ QUERY   | ADD    | DELETE  | COPY    |
               SAVE    | LOAD   | UNLOAD  | RESTORE |
               COMPARE | EXPORT | IMPORT  | FLAGS ]

Return Code: (Except for REG COMPARE)

  0 - Successful
  1 - Failed

For help on a specific operation type:

  REG Operation /?

Examples:

  REG QUERY /?
  REG ADD /?
  REG DELETE /?
  REG COPY /?
  REG SAVE /?
  REG RESTORE /?
  REG LOAD /?
  REG UNLOAD /?
  REG COMPARE /?
  REG EXPORT /?
  REG IMPORT /?
  REG FLAGS /?

C:\Windows\system32>
```

But with Windows XP x86:

```
Microsoft Windows XP [Version 5.1.2600]
(C) Copyright 1985-2001 Microsoft Corp.

C:\Documents and Settings\chris>cd \WINDOWS\system32

C:\WINDOWS\system32>reg.exe

Console Registry Tool for Windows - version 3.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corp. 1981-2001.  All rights reserved


REG Operation [Parameter List]

  Operation  [ QUERY   | ADD    | DELETE  | COPY    |
               SAVE    | LOAD   | UNLOAD  | RESTORE |
               COMPARE | EXPORT | IMPORT ]

Return Code: (Except of REG COMPARE)

  0 - Succussful
  1 - Failed

For help on a specific operation type:

  REG Operation /?

Examples:

  REG QUERY /?
  REG ADD /?
  REG DELETE /?
  REG COPY /?
  REG SAVE /?
  REG RESTORE /?
  REG LOAD /?
  REG UNLOAD /?
  REG COMPARE /?
  REG EXPORT /?
  REG IMPORT /?

C:\WINDOWS\system32>copy reg.exe reg2.exe
        1 file(s) copied.

C:\WINDOWS\system32>reg2.exe

Console Registry Tool for Windows - version 3.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corp. 1981-2001.  All rights reserved


REG Operation [Parameter List]

  Operation  [ QUERY   | ADD    | DELETE  | COPY    |
               SAVE    | LOAD   | UNLOAD  | RESTORE |
               COMPARE | EXPORT | IMPORT ]

Return Code: (Except of REG COMPARE)

  0 - Succussful
  1 - Failed

For help on a specific operation type:

  REG Operation /?

Examples:

  REG QUERY /?
  REG ADD /?
  REG DELETE /?
  REG COPY /?
  REG SAVE /?
  REG RESTORE /?
  REG LOAD /?
  REG UNLOAD /?
  REG COMPARE /?
  REG EXPORT /?
  REG IMPORT /?

C:\WINDOWS\system32>
```

WinDbg seems to tell me that the CRT is killing it:

```
Child-SP          RetAddr           Call Site
00000000`0016f798 00000000`779d2f8b ntdll!ZwTerminateProcess+0xa
00000000`0016f7a0 000007fe`fe97d832 ntdll!RtlExitUserProcess+0x8b
00000000`0016f7d0 00000000`ffe7f710 msvcrt!cinit+0x13b
00000000`0016f810 00000000`778a495d reg!DynArrayGetItemType2+0x1fc
00000000`0016f850 00000000`779d8791 kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0xd
00000000`0016f880 00000000`00000000 ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart+0x1d
```

But as i'm not too experienced with WinDbg (and this one is 64bit, so, say, Ollydbg fails) i'm sort of at a loss here. Thanks for any information you guys have.

## Edit

Thanks to CyberShadow's help and a bit of googling, I found the solution: it looks for .mui (it's translation) in a subfolder of the current language installed.

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.0.6001]
Copyright (c) 2006 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Windows\system32>cd en-US

C:\Windows\System32\en-US>copy reg.exe.mui reg2.exe.mui
        1 file(s) copied.

C:\Windows\System32\en-US>cd ..

C:\Windows\System32>reg2
ERROR: Invalid syntax.
Type "REG /?" for usage.

C:\Windows\System32>del en-US\reg2.exe.mui

C:\Windows\System32>reg2

C:\Windows\System32>
```

Comment: I see the same thing on Win7 x64.  Copying reg.exe to another directory fails in the same way.  Seems like a security check to make sure you are running exactly "reg.exe" from the system directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By playing around a bit with a debugger, I found that LoadString (which is used to get the usage and error messages) returns ERROR_MUI_FILE_NOT_LOADED. I think that somewhat explains it :)

Notes:

- That stack trace seems to be misleading (or at least we're seeing different problems with the same effect). The application exits normally without printing anything when copied/renamed.
- Other than not being able to display messages, the utility continues to work just fine.
- This also affects the 32-bit version (which you can find in SysWOW64).

Comment: Thanks for the info, I thought it was something silly like that. Any idea how to reassociate the MUI file with the renamed copy?

As long as the executable still goes ahead and does it's thing, that is good to know. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Thanks again, I found the MUI it wanted. I realize the stack trace I posted was after process exit - it makes sense that after it was done with everything, it called ExitProcess. Sorry for the misleading trace. Updated the question with the solution.

Comment: Ah yes, that'd do it. Find reg.exe.mui and rename it too, and it'll all work.

Answer (score 0):

Wild guess here, but some apps use the name of the application to determine what it should do - this is an old UNIX trick; for example, `/bin/false` and `/bin/true` are identical binaries, but the name determines which result to return.

You do this when you end up writing 2+ programs that are 99.9% identical, and you don't want to maintain separate codebases for each.

Comment: I thought it might be this, but I didn't think MS would do it (and it appears they haven't, see CyberShadow's response)